# Android show description of what a button does when user performs a long touch on it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-event

In my Android app, I want users to be able to learn what a button does by performing a long touch on it, showing a description that looks like the "More options" description of an overflow menu button.

[image: More options]

Also, can I disable the vibration that is caused by long clicking the overflow menu and can I disable the description altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [Toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) message on item long click and set toast message to gravity top

Comment: Thank you. Android has some weird naming conventions. Do you know how I can disable or edit the toast that shows when I long click the overflow menu icon on the toolbar?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Whenever I long click the overflow menu icon https://prnt.sc/g0m0p0 (the button that is circled red), a toast saying "More options" appears. How can I  edit the text of the toast, so it just says "Options".